# Ionic : How to make Angular Translate js working with Search Filter when language changed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-filters, angular-translate

> **Solved the issue.  Solution is edited in this question. Thank you "praszyk".**

I'm not able to make Angular Translate working with Search Filter . When the language is English the list items are searchable in english asusual. But when the language is in Bangla the items are still searchable in English but not in Bangla. Is there any solution?

View

```
<ion-list>
            <ion-item>
              <label class="item item-input">
                <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
                <input type="text" ng-model="input.filterUser" placeholder="Search">
              </label>
            </ion-item>
              <ion-item class="item-avatar" ng-repeat="user in groups | filter:input.filterUser">
                <img src="{{user.avatar}}">           
                <h2>{{user.name | translate}}</h2>
                <p>{{user.fullname}}
                  {{user.email}}</p>       
              </ion-item>        
          </ion-list>
```

Controller

```
.controller('CreditCtrl', function($scope, $ionicConfig, $translate) {

  $scope.input = {};  
  $scope.groups = [
  {
  index: 1,
  index_start_at: 56,
  name:  "Bnd_Nilgiri",
  surname: "Hayes",
  fullname: "Grace Beatty",
  email: "francis@livingston.es",
  bool: false,
  avatar: "img/ionic.png"
  },
  {
  index: 2,
  index_start_at: 57,
  name: "Bnd_Nilachal",
  surname: "Shayes",
  fullname: "Srace Beatty",
  email: "shuvo@livingston.es",
  bool: false,
  avatar: "img/ionic.png"
  }
];



 angular.forEach($scope.groups, function(user, index){
      $translate(user.name, {user: user}).then(function(translated){
        $scope.groups[index].name = translated;
      });
    });

})
```

Translation Provider

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider, $translateProvider) {

 $translateProvider.translations('en', {
    Bnd_Nilgiri : 'Nilgiri Tourspot',
    Bnd_Nilachal : 'Nilachal Tourspot',
    Bnd_Bogalake : 'Bogalake Tourspot',    
  });
  $translateProvider.translations('de', {
    // Bandarban Tour Spots

    Bnd_Nilgiri : 'নিলগিরি ট্যুর স্পট',
    Bnd_Nilachal : 'নিলাচল ট্যুর স্পট',
    Bnd_Bogalake : 'বগালেক ট্যুর স্পট',
  });
  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because your `| translate` filter is applied after the angular filter.

The only possible solution would be to translate the array `groups` beforehand.
You would need to use the `$translate` service in your controller before applying it to the `groups` variable:

```
var en_translations =  {
    Bnd_Nilgiri : 'Nilgiri Tourspot',
    Bnd_Nilachal : 'Nilachal Tourspot',
    Bnd_Bogalake : 'Bogalake Tourspot',    
}

var de_translations = {
    Bnd_Nilgiri : 'নিলগিরি ট্যুর স্পট',
    Bnd_Nilachal : 'নিলাচল ট্যুর স্পট',
    Bnd_Bogalake : 'বগালেক ট্যুর স্পট',
};


var app = angular.module('myApp', ['pascalprecht.translate']);

app.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
  // add translation table
  $translateProvider
    .translations('en', en_translations)
    .translations('de', de_translations)
    .preferredLanguage('de');
}]);

app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$translate', function ($scope, $translate) {
  // expose translation via `$translate` service
  $scope.groups =  [
    {
      index: 1,
      index_start_at: 56,
      name:  "Bnd_Nilgiri",
      surname: "Hayes",
      fullname: "Grace Beatty",
      email: "francis@livingston.es",
      bool: false,
      avatar: "img/ionic.png"
    },
    {
      index: 2,
      index_start_at: 57,
      name: "Bnd_Nilachal",
      surname: "Shayes",
      fullname: "Srace Beatty",
      email: "shuvo@livingston.es",
      bool: false,
      avatar: "img/ionic.png"
    }
  ];
  angular.forEach($scope.groups, function(user, index){
    $translate(user.name, {user: user}).then(function(translated){
      $scope.groups[index].name = translated;
    });
  });

}]);
```

I didn't test the code but that's the way to roll here I imagine. 
Basically `filter:input.filterUser` operates on the `$scope.groups` array which isn't translated yet so you need to translate it before `ng-repeat` takes place.

**EDIT**: I made a plunkr here to showcase the code above:
http://plnkr.co/edit/sVgUIlFxfs6pDsdR2ydQ

Comment: Thank you praszyk for taking time and answering my question. My controller is like the code of the question, I just edited. Please have a look.

Comment: Can you post parts of your translation object?

Comment: 1 min . I'm editing the question again. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Thank you very much. It works.